# Is Chromium installed on my Mac or not?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, virus

I have Chrome installed on my Mac and use it as my default Browser. I remember, a few weeks ago I got a notification that said something like "Allow notificatoins from Chromium...". I quickly swiped it away (reflex), so I don't know much about that. I never installed Chromium on my Mac, and I also search everywhere, didn't find it.

I've read on the internet there are viruses that pretend to be Chromium on Macs, that's why I came here.

Now when I wanted to select an application to open a .pdf file, Chromium appeared in the list, see for yourself on the screenshot.

I can't find Chromium in my ApplicationS folderS (both of them), I also can't find it with command+space.

Do I have a virus on my Mac?

[image: Screenshot: Open With menu]

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `ls -ld /Applications/*hrom*.app ` and add the result to the question?

Comment: @nohillside result: 
zsh: no matches found: /Applications/*hrom*.app

Comment: Hmm, where did you install Chrome to?

Comment: You do not have a virus. There is no Chromium virus. There is Chromium modified and hijacked to mine your personal data, which is more like a trojan horse than anything else. Clearly, though, your system sees that you have Chromium installed somewhere. I'd suggest downloading EasyFinder and using it to search your hard drive(s) to see where it is.

Comment: @nohillside to the Applications folder inside my personal folder (not the global one)

Comment: @FeliniusRex Not sure we have enough information yet for such a claim.

Comment: Ok, `ls -ld ~/Applications/*hrom*.app` then :-) Or just use Spotlight to search for Chromium, use cursor down to select the application found and press Cmd to have the path shown to the right of the name.

Comment: @nohillside To each their own. I'm sticking by my claim that the OP does not have something that does not exist (Chromium virus), and I've explained why a virus and a trojan are different. He seems to have, or at one time, had, Chromium installed whether through a dodgy bundle or through simply forgetting he had downloaded it.

Comment: my Mac is quite new and I'm 100% certain I never downloaded chromium

Comment: It seems that blizzard are moving over to a chromium based launcher. So it could be that.

Comment: Some apps do have other apps inside them. I would use something like EasyFind to search for the app.

Answer (score 2):

The open with menu just reads the launch services database.

Normally this database self cleans, but can need a clean wipe on occasion.

- [Duplicate entries in "Open With" menu in Finder even after rebuilding Launch Services](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/77644/5472)

Whether or not a virus is installed won’t be determined by this alone. You’ll want to scan for that using a tool you trust or erase install and review all apps and extensions manually if that’s to your taste.